# Application not responding, why doesn't ANR popup display?

Tags: android, performance-testing, android-anr-dialog

I want to **test** my application which is not responding. The button in the code below runs an infinite loop but the ANR popup doesn't show.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"ahmet vefa saruhan",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

fun buttonClickec2( v : View) { //after button click
    while(true) {
        //Nothing to do, why doesn't ANR show?
    }
}
```

Please read question carefully. The question is about the ANR popup.

Comment: You should read the documentation, search StackOverflow questions and then open a new one :). You would find the answer to it already. Docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts

Comment: Well, your text is not in English so I don't know what is ahmet vefa sarauhan. If you want to block the UI thread then you should read the docs, search so, still applies to what I told you. Do not ask without doing your own search.

Comment: Are you trying to change ANR Message?

Comment: no I just want to see ANR popup. main thread is blocking but not showing popup

Comment: @ahmetvefa53 Why do you want a popup, just fix the root cause so that the main thread doesn't block. Also worth noting that Android shows ANR dialogs for apps that take too long to process the broadcast message only if Show all ANRs is enabled in the device’s Developer options. For this reason, background ANR dialogs are not always displayed to the user, but the app could still be experiencing performance issues.

Comment: @Dayan thanks for your answer.I just want to test popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to purposely display the ANR Popup dialog by causing an infinite loop.

```
fun buttonClickec2( v : View) { //after button click
    while(true) {
        //Nothing to do, why doesn't ANR show?
    }
}
```

As per Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr):

> Android shows ANR dialogs for apps that take too long to process the
>   broadcast message only if Show all ANRs is enabled in the device’s
>   Developer options. For this reason, background ANR dialogs are not
>   always displayed to the user, but the app could still be experiencing
>   performance issues.

Comment: thank you Sir .It is satisfied answer and I did not know this information .

Comment: @ahmetvefa53 You are welcome, glad it cleared it up a bit for you.

Answer (score 0):

use show method to display the toast.

```
Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"ahmet vefa saruhan",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```